# KDB type error - whilst using functional select/updates

Tags: function, loops, functional-programming, typeerror, kdb

I have the below two functions - the idea here is that id like to create percentiles of bpsAum for different programmes, i also have another function for bpsTrn, id like the limits table to be one single function that both can share. This however, returns a type error, I think it has to do with me using functional selects and updates within the functions. would appreciate any advice here. Outside of the function, running line by line this works fine, just not when packaged into function.

```
.tca.dailySlippageDistribution4:{[Dte;lookback;thresh]
tab:select bpsAum:(sum ArrivalSlippageUSD % first TradingLevel),sum TurnoverUSD by ProgrammeName,date from fullSlipTable where date within(Dte - 1500;Dte);
    prog: exec distinct ProgrammeName from tab;
    dtes: exec distinct date from tab;
    Dte2:Dte - lookback;
    Dte2:?[Dte2 in dtes;Dte2;?[(Dte2-1) in dtes;Dte2:Dte2-1;?[(Dte2-2) in dtes;Dte2:(Dte2-2);Dte2]]];
    Dte:?[Dte in dtes;Dte;?[(Dte-1) in dtes;Dte:Dte-1;?[(Dte-2) in dtes;Dte:(Dte-2);Dte]]];
    st:dtes?Dte;
    ed:dtes?Dte2;
    distwindow:(st-ed)-1;
    metric:`bpsAum;
    maW:0;
    Limits:(uj/){[tab;thresh;distwindow;metric;maW;x] LimitsTable4[tab;thresh;distwindow;metric;maW;x]}[tab;thresh;distwindow;metric;maW;] each prog;
    tab:ej[`date`ProgrammeName;tab;Limits];
    tab};

LimitsTable4:{[tab;thresh;distwindow;metric;maW;prog]
    tab: select from tab where ProgrammeName = prog;
    tab:$[metric ~ `bpsTrn;![tab;();0b;(enlist `maRunRate)!(enlist (mavg;maW;metric))];tab];
    dateList: exec date from tab;
    LList:$[`maRunRate in cols tab;?[tab;();();`maRunRate];?[tab;();();`metric]];
    ltk:`float$swin[.dashFn.getPercentile[thresh(1);];distwindow;LList];
    utk:`float$swin[.dashFn.getPercentile[thresh(0);];distwindow;LList];
    tab:?[metric ~ `bpsAum;([]date:dateList;ProgrammeName:prog;bpsAum:LList;upperLimit:utk;lowerLimit:ltk);([]date:dateList;ProgrammeName:prog;maBpsTrn:LList;upperLimit:utk;lowerLimit:ltk)];
    tab:(-1*distwindow)# tab};
```

Comment: Nothing is glaring out at me but there's a lot going on here. Take a look at what is being returned by the `each prog` before the `(uj/)` in `.tca.dailySlippageDistribution4`. Perhaps you are getting one odd result from one `prog` messing up the `uj`.

i.e.
`: {[tab;thresh;distwindow;metric;maW;x] LimitsTable4[tab;thresh;distwindow;metric;maW;x]}[tab;thresh;distwindow;metric;maW;] each prog;`.

It will be difficult to help without providing an example for such a complicated function.

Comment: as a side note, this doesn't need to be nested in another lambda, could just be:

`: LimitsTable4[tab;thresh;distwindow;metric;maW;] each prog;`

Comment: To Matts point there's a lot going on and it will be impossible for us to properly debug/test, however some other things I noticed: 1. You shouldn't use `?` for non-vector if-elses, you should use `$`. The vector conditional `?` isn't just an if-else, it evaluates *BOTH* outcomes before picking one, and this means that you're unintentionally subtracting from Dte2 multiple times in this line: `Dte2:?[Dte2 in dtes;Dte2;?[(Dte2-1) in dtes;Dte2:Dte2-1;?[(Dte2-2) in dtes;Dte2:(Dte2-2);Dte2]]];`. 2. I think ```?[tab;();();`metric]``` is an error, I think it should be `?[tab;();();metric]`

Comment: hi both - thankyou - it turns out it was due to how i was passing the function into the limits table that was the issue, instead of creating variables metric and maw - i directly inserted into the function - then project x into it. And also the error terry points out i changed so metric was not passed as a symbol and that seemed to work. appreciate the correction to Dte section. I instead used dtes?max dtes where dtes > Dte -3, which seems like a much easier work around.